# Load script file in partial views

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm having a problem with my ASP.NET MVC project.

In my project, the user navigate between pages with tabs,
every click on tab calls in ajax request to partial view and printing the relevant HTML.

The problem happens when the partial view contains, for example:

```
<script src="bla.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
```

First of all, after I loaded the partial view, I can't find the script tag in the page source (or Inspect Elements in chrome).
I don't know what the browser does with that script but the second problem, that every time it's loaded again and again.

For example, if I have this event listener in my script file:

```
$("#button").live("click", function() { console.log("sdf") })
```

this method will happen again and again due the times the user navigates to this page. If it's the second time, the event listener will call twice.

Comment: Put the scripts in the main view, or in the layout (and `.live` has been depreciated - use `.on`)

Comment: I cant put it in the layout cause the js code depends on HTML elements that doesnt exist in some cases

Comment: Then that's why you use event delegation using `.on` - e.g. `$(document).on('click', '#button', function() { ...` (but you should ideally replace `document` with the closest ancestor that exists in the main view when the view is first rendered)

Comment: Bind events to containers on your main view, include script on main view. Render partials in said containers.

Answer (score -1):

Try Unbinding the funtion and bind it back again...

```
$(function(){

        $("#button").unbind('click').bind("click", function() { console.log("sdf") });
```

});

Hope That Helps.

Comment: Using delegates on the main page would be a far better solution.

Comment: The Above function can be seperated out wherever he wants to put it in. If this is to be put on partial page than this function will only bind on the perticular partial page after the html render. Also everytime the function will rebind to the button so the problem for hitting twice will be maintainable.
Just a thought.